# Kubernetes ReplicaFailure FailedCreate but no events

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

I have deployment and a replica set in Kubernetes that are failing to create a pod.  I've tried

`kubectl describe deployment deployment-name` and

`kubectl describe replicaset replicaset-name`

And they both say

```
Conditions:
  Type             Status  Reason
  ----             ------  ------
  ReplicaFailure   True    FailedCreate
Events:            <none>
```

All of the troubleshooting guides I've seen rely on information from the Events section but it says `<none>` in my case.  How can I get more information to debug the problem?

Comment: Share your yaml

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the [docs are pretty clear](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#failed-deployment)  on how to debug this. This is a 'failed' deployment and possible causes:

- Insufficient quota
- Readiness probe failures
- Image pull errors
- Insufficient permissions
- Limit ranges
- Application runtime misconfiguration

You can try to debug for example by patching the `progressDeadlineSeconds` deployment spec field to something long.

```sh
kubectl patch deployment.v1.apps/deployment-name -p '{"spec":{"progressDeadlineSeconds":600}}'
```

Maybe you have a [ReplicaSet resource quota](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/#object-count-quota)❓

✌️

Comment: Thank you, I was exceeding the CPU resource quota. I was able to see the error when viewing the Replica Set json from the UI

Answer (score 61):

Describe replicaset will give you the error that is causing failure with deployment object.

```
./kubectl describe replicaset <replica-set-name>
```

Example error:

```
  Type     Reason            Age                From                   Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----                   -------
  Normal   SuccessfulCreate  13m                replicaset-controller  Created pod: pod
  Warning  FailedCreate      13m                replicaset-controller  Error creating: pods "pod" is forbidden: exceeded quota: custom-resource-quota, requested: cpu=510m, used: cpu=1630m, limited: cpu=2
```